# Whitelisting Azure Kubernetes external IP in azure App Service

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-appservice

I have a ingress controller loadbalancer for kubernetes cluster which has an external IP
I have another app service which has network restrictions. I should be able to acess this App Service with the external IP of k8s, i have from above load balancer by whitelisting it.
I have whitelisted but it is not working and it is giving 403 forbidden as response.

Is this is the IP we should use for whitelisting or do we have to do any other process. I have used this load balancer IP for subdomain mapping as well and it is working fine but unable to access App service when i whitelisted it but I am able to access App service when i have whitelisted a other vm IP address.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Azure CNI, Pod IPs are first-class members in the virtual network. You should add an allow rule for the entire Kubernetes Pod IP range to make this work.

If you want more control over the outgoing IP address you can set that up with  an egress gateway in your service mesh of choice. For example [Istio](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway/).

Comment: we deploy the NGINX ingress controller in an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster. The ingress controller is configured with a static public IP address on Azure Standard Load Balancer. The cert-manager project is used to automatically generate and configure Let’s Encrypt certificates. Custom domain will be integrated with certificate to run the application publicly.

Comment: The external IP of the ingress controller has nothing to do with the source IP used by your Pods to initiate an egress connection.

Comment: Thankyou for the quick reply. Since the loadbalancer external IP is not related can you please mention the method how to get the external IP of the kubernetes pod if i setup azure CNI and give that IP to app service will it work ?

Comment: As I said in my answer, you will have to add the entire Pod IP *range* to the allowlist. (Pod IPs will change every time a Pod is recreated.)